# Is a tag that is *operating system* specific useful?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, review-lists

For instance, [db2-luw](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2-luw) referring to DB2 for Linux, Unix, or Windows as opposed to just [db2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2) ?

Also, when approving tag wiki edits, it would be great to be able to see proposed edits made against both the excerpt as well as the main body in a single review task... I just rejected a tag body edit for [db2-luw](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2-luw) because it didn't explain what `luw` was; however the very next review task was for the excerpt of [db2-luw](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2-luw) which *did* explain what `luw` was.  If I would have been able to see the excerpt with the body, or at least the excerpt first, I would have approved the edit.

Comment: As a general rule, I would say no but my understanding for DB2 is that there is an a difference in capabilities and administration for `luw` vs `zOS`

Comment: If we ever did agree the need for this sort of tag, it'd be in addition to the base RDBWS tag rather than an alternative to it of course, is that what you meant?

Comment: Precisely, @JackDouglas - I was wondering if it is necessary to have multiple tags for a single piece of tech.  I guess in this particular case, I would lean towards having a single tag, and tagging the question with whatever O/S tag is appropriate if the O/S makes a huge difference to the question or answer.

Comment: Although, having said that, I can now see this is similar to the situation with [tag:sql-server] and [tag:sql-server-2012] (ie, various versions of a piece of tech have their own tag already).

Comment: Yup, that is the analogy I had in mind too, though [tag:dbcc] is not [tag:sql-server-dbcc]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always remember that tags are intended to make it easier to find a question, not to find the most Type-A classification of questions. You get 5 of them. I expect it would be easier to just tag with the OS involved if you need to narrow it down.

Comment: Nice succinct answer - that's why you're such a great mod!

Comment: Thanks, felt a little snarky >.<

Answer (score 4):

In the case of MySQL, some features taken for granted in Linux are not available in Windows.

The first thing that came to mind was the option [**innodb_flush_method**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method). In Linux, it allows InnoDB to bypass caching to the OS and explicit caches to the system tablespace. [That feature is not available in the Windows version (since Windows will cache in the OS against your will)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30386/877).

Recently, [someone asked a question involving mysqldump in Windows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54538/mysqldump-on-specific-db-date/54547#54547). The word windows was not highlighted or overly emphasized. It was not even tagged as <kbd>windows</kbd>. (I added the tag later). I answered the question based on seeing that word 'windows'. Had I not seen the word 'windows', I would have answered in terms of Linux shell scripting instead of Windows batch commands.

SQL Server obviously does not need a <kbd>windows</kbd> tag since it is a Window product.

PostgreSQL and Oracle have versions available for Windows.

Answers based on OS platform have a bearing on

- How much memory can be allocated
- What kind of disk layouts are feasible
- How the OS caches disk changes

Tags for the OS make sense. A tag should not have the product and OS combined as a single token. If a posted question has a product and the question is something that is specific to the product but agnostic to the OS, an OS tag should not be used.